# Change focus to next input field on "Enter" key with VueJS & Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I have a form that works strictly with a Barcode code that simulates an Enter event at the end of the read. (No keyboard and mouse). I'm having a hard time sending the focus to the next element (input sometimes a button). I prepared a playground for you so you can checkout my code. At some point this worked before a quasar dress-up and now it isn't. I refuse to think this is a quasar issue and more like a "I suck" problem lol.

The process is simple in theory. Wait for the input field to read the entire barcode before it fires the focus event. My best guess is to use the change event. When I tried the input or keydown event, it registered other stuff and fired other functions on every digit.. Big no-no, especially when making api calls.

Here is my sendFocus method.

```
sendFocus: function(e) {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var input = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input";
        var form = e.target.form;
        if (e.key === "Enter" && input) {
            var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, e.target);
            form.elements[index + 1].focus();
        }
    });
}
```

And the link to the [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/JjdoMbo?editable=true&editors=101). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `@change` (or native DOM `onchange`) event, any associated handler will get invoked as many times as you hit a key on the keyboard, and in your case, you are literally attaching a new handler every time a key is pressed (you seem to be good with Javascript and jQuery, so I hope the codepen was just for mere illustration... Unless I'm missing something?).

But anyway, in Vue (for this particular purpose), we usually want `@keydown.enter`. Have a read on [Event Handling with Key Codes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Codes).

That being said, there are several approaches to achieving this "jump-to-next-field" behavior, but please consider the following example (which should also be applicable to Quasar's `q-input`).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  methods: {
    focusNext(e) {
      const inputs = Array.from(e.target.form.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'));
      const index = inputs.indexOf(e.target);

      if (index < inputs.length) {
        inputs[index + 1].focus();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Field #1</label>
      <input type="text" @keydown.enter="focusNext" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field #2</label>
      <input type="text" @keydown.enter="focusNext" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field #3</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! And yes, I developed with jQuery for a very long time and I'm still getting used to vue. I appreciate this!

Comment: Actually, something is missing. It appears that it only works if there is an input field next to go to. The last input field is not transferring focus to the button for example. I could cheat and make a hidden input to accept the barcode read for the button but if it can go to the button itself, the barcode gun can still fire it. I just the ficus there first.

Comment: Nevermind. I went about it differently. I used your code. and transferred the focus manually to the button I wanted to. I think it works better this way since there are several buttons in the form and I don't want the focus to go to another button. Thanks again

Comment: Glad that did it . If the final input to jump to is a submit button (`input[type=submit]`), maybe reducing the selector specificity to just `input` rather than `input[type=text] ` would help?